# Cancel all asyncio tasks/discord py loops

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have a discord py bot that has 8 or so loops constantly running. Sometimes these loops will stop for no apparent reason (ie I'm not seeing any exceptions thrown).

I've heard the best way to "restart" these loops is to unload and load the Cog containing the loops which can be done by `self.bot.reload_extension(cog)`. I have this, but apparently reloading an extension doesn't stop any running loops, which means my bot now does each loop twice.

I need to restart the tasks, and I've been looking how to do this but I'm not finding any success. Here's what I have so far (from https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel):

If I go through this function, it will find all the tasks and hit the cancel twice, await twice, but  but then stop. No more loops will be processed, no errors will be thrown.

```
    async def CancelLoops(self):
        tasks = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()      
            try:
                await task
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                print("Cancelled now")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your loops should be run someway like this:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def my_first_loop():
    # Do something here
    pass
```

If that's the case then the way to restart your loop would be like this

```py
@my_first_loop.error
async def my_first_loop_error_handler(ctx,error):
    if isInstance(error, YourErrorClass):
        # do this and that
        my_first_loop.restart()
```